# How is filters UIScrollView/UICollectionView in Apple's Photos app implemented that it opens so fast?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, core-image

I'm not asking about the exact code but the overall idea.

Here is my problem: I'm trying to create something similar to filter choosing UI in Photos app. I've tried multiple approaches and all of them have their drawbacks.

1) I've tried using `Operation` and `OperationQueue` with a collection view, which prefetching is enabled. This loads the viewController fast but drops frames while scrolling.

2) Right now I'm using a scroll view and `GCD` but it loads the viewController too long (because it applies all filters to all the buttons inside it at once), but then it scrolls smoothly.

**NOTE:**  To answer the question, there is no need to read the below part (I believe), however if you are interested in how I try to implement the functionality you're welcome to read it.

For the implementation of all filters I use a struct called `Filters` which is responsible for initiating each filter and appending it to an array.

```
struct Filters {
var image: UIImage
var allFilters: [CIFilter] = []

init(image: UIImage) {

    self.image = image

    guard  let sepia = Sepia(image: image) else {return}

    allFilters.append(contentsOf: [sepia, sepia, sepia, sepia, sepia, sepia, sepia, sepia, sepia, sepia, sepia, sepia, sepia])

       }
  }
```

Right now I'm using only one filter. `Sepia` is a subclass of `CIFilter`. I've created it as a subclass because in future I'm going to create a custom one from it. Here is its implementation:

```
class Sepia: CIFilter {

var inputImage: CIImage?
var inputIntensity: NSNumber?

@objc override var filterName: String? {
    return NSLocalizedString("Sepia", comment: "Name of a Filter")
}

convenience init?(image: UIImage, inputIntensity: NSNumber? = nil) {
    self.init()

    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
        return nil
    }

    if inputIntensity != nil {
        self.inputIntensity = inputIntensity
    } else {
        self.setDefaults()
    }

    let inputImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    self.inputImage = inputImage
}

override func setDefaults() {
    inputIntensity = 1.0
}

override var outputImage: CIImage? {
    guard let inputImage = inputImage, let inputIntensity = inputIntensity else {
        return nil
    }

    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone", withInputParameters: [kCIInputImageKey: inputImage, kCIInputIntensityKey: inputIntensity])

   return filter?.outputImage

  }
}
```

In the viewController's `viewDidLoad` I initiate `Filters` struct:

```
self.filters = Filters(image: image)
```

Then I call a method that configures some views (`filterViews`) based on the number of filters in the `filters.allFilters` array and iterates over them and calls a method which takes a thumbnail `UIImage` and applies a filter to it and then returns it in a completion handler (I use `DispatchGroup` in it for debugging reasons). Here is the method that applies a filter to a thumbnail:

```
func imageWithFilter(filter: CIFilter, completion: @escaping(UIImage?)->Void) {

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        guard let outputImage = filter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage, let cgImageResult = self.context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) else  {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 completion(nil)
            }
            group.leave()
            return
        }

        let filteredImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageResult)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print (filteredImage)
            completion(filteredImage)

        }

       group.leave()
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        print ("Filteres are set")
    }
}
```

The print statement above and the filtered image address are printed quite soon, however the images don't appear inside the views.

I have tried to use `Time Profiler` but it gives me some weird results. For example, it shows the following as taking quite long to execute in the root of backtrace:
[image]

When I try to see the code in Xcode, I get the following, which doesn't help much:
[image]

So, this is the problem. If you have any ideas how it is implemented in the Photos app that it is so fast and responsive, or if you have suggestions about my implementation, I would highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Some general rules of thumb regarding CoreImage. (1) Render using a `GLKView` or `MTKView`. That way you can simply use the CIImage, and you can only create a UIImage *only* when necessary. Also both of these use the GPU to render, not the CPU. (2) I'm not seeing something in the code you posted, but make sure that *if* you are using a `CIContext`, you create a single one and share it (and if you're not, consider using one).

Comment: A very brief introduction about contexts and threading can be found in a free iBook (also available as a PDF) called *Core Image for Swift* by Simon Gladman. Pages 9-10. It's written in Swift 2 so much of the code may need to be tweaked, but it should be accurate.

Comment: @dfd, thank you for your answer. I'll look at the book today. I haven't heard anything about `GLKView` or `MTKView`, so I guess, I have to read the docs. About the context: I create a single one with `EAGL context` and share it.

Comment: The book also addresses GLKViews. It touches on using MTKView (which is Metal). A single EAGL context is the way to go. One last thing - starting with iOS 12 Apple has "deprecated" all things OpenGL including GLKViews. They want you to use `Metal 2`, which was introduced during WWDC '17. I write my own `CIKernels` and will be working to update some "warp" and "general" kernel code in September, but I have gotten a MTKView to work. While it is not really an answer, I'll post one with formatted code to help you out.

Comment: @dfd, ok, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question seems to be how to display the CIImage resulting from a Core Image CIFilter as fast as possible — so fast that it appears instantly when the view controller appears; so fast, in fact, that the user can adjust the CIFilter parameters using sliders and so forth, and the image will redisplay live and keep up with the adjustment.

The answer is to use Metal Kit, and in particular a MTKView. The rendering work is moved off onto the device's GPU and is extremely fast, fast enough to come in under the refresh rate of the device's screen so that there is no discernible lag as the user twiddles the sliders.

I have a simple demonstration where the user applies a custom chain of filters called VignetteFilter:

[image]

As the user slides the slider, the amount of vignetting (the inner circle) changes smoothly. At every instant of sliding, a new filter is being applied to the original image and the filter is rendered, over and over as the user slides the slider, keeping up in synch with the user's movements.

The view at the bottom, as I said, is an MTKView. MTKView is not hard to work with in this way; it does require some preparation but it's all boilerplate. The only tricky part is actually getting the image to come out where you want it.

Here's the code for my view controller (I'm omitting everything but the slider and the display of the filtered image):

```
class EditingViewController: UIViewController, MTKViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var mtkview: MTKView!

    var context : CIContext!
    let displayImage : CIImage! // must be set before viewDidLoad
    let vig = VignetteFilter()
    var queue: MTLCommandQueue!

    // slider value changed
    @IBAction func doSlider(_ sender: Any?) {
        self.mtkview.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // preparation, all pure boilerplate

        self.mtkview.isOpaque = false // otherwise background is black
        // must have a "device"
        guard let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() else {
            return
        }
        self.mtkview.device = device

        // mode: draw on demand
        self.mtkview.isPaused = true
        self.mtkview.enableSetNeedsDisplay = true

        self.context = CIContext(mtlDevice: device)
        self.queue = device.makeCommandQueue()

        self.mtkview.delegate = self
        self.mtkview.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {
    }

    func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        // run the displayImage thru the CIFilter
        self.vig.setValue(self.displayImage, forKey: "inputImage")
        let val = Double(self.slider.value)
        self.vig.setValue(val, forKey:"inputPercentage")
        var output = self.vig.outputImage!

        // okay, `output` is the CIImage we want to display
        // scale it down to aspect-fit inside the MTKView
        var r = view.bounds
        r.size = view.drawableSize
        r = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: output.extent.size, insideRect: r)
        output = output.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(
            scaleX: r.size.width/output.extent.size.width, 
            y: r.size.height/output.extent.size.height))
        let x = -r.origin.x
        let y = -r.origin.y

        // minimal dance required in order to draw: render, present, commit
        let buffer = self.queue.makeCommandBuffer()!
        self.context!.render(output,
            to: view.currentDrawable!.texture,
            commandBuffer: buffer,
            bounds: CGRect(origin:CGPoint(x:x, y:y), size:view.drawableSize),
            colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB())
        buffer.present(view.currentDrawable!)
        buffer.commit()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am already using `MetalKit` for that. Just wanted to be sure that it is indeed done in that way :)

Comment: Well, I can’t see into Apple’s apps. But there is no _other_ way to render a CIImage quickly, now that OpenGL is deprecated.

Comment: MUCH better answer than mine. Upvoted and consider mine gone.

Comment: @dfd Sorry about that, but I was so hoping that you were about to divulge the secret of CIFilter and MTKView that I was disappointed when the plot flagged in the middle... :) So in the end I had to do it myself, like the Little Red Hen.