# What is the most optimized way of changing alpha of blended images in CoreImage in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I want to blend two images with darkenBlendMode and using Slider to manipulate alpha of first and second image. Unfortunately my method is laggy on iPhone 6S. I know that problem is in calling "loadImage" function in every Slider touch but I have no idea how to make it less aggravating. Have you any idea how to repair it?

```
extension UIImage {

    func alpha(_ value:CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        draw(at: CGPoint.zero, blendMode: .normal, alpha: value)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage!
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var image: Image?
    @State private var opacity: CGFloat = 0
    let context = CIContext()

    var body: some View {

        return VStack(alignment: .center) {
            image?
                .resizable()
                .padding(14.0)
                .scaledToFit()

            Slider(value: Binding(
                get: {
                    self.opacity
                },
                set: {(newValue) in
                      self.opacity = newValue
                      self.loadImage()
                }
            ), in: -0.5...0.5)
        }
        .onAppear(perform: loadImage)

    }

    func loadImage(){
        let uiInputImage = UIImage(named: "photo1")!.alpha(0.5 + opacity)

        let uiBackgroundInputImage = UIImage(named: "photo2")!.alpha(0.5 - opacity)

        let ciInputImage = CIImage(image: uiInputImage)
        let ciBackgroundInputImage = CIImage(image: uiBackgroundInputImage)


        let currentFilter = CIFilter.darkenBlendMode()

        currentFilter.inputImage = ciInputImage

        currentFilter.backgroundImage = ciBackgroundInputImage

        guard let blendedImage = currentFilter.outputImage else {return}

        if let cgBlendedImage = context.createCGImage(blendedImage, from: blendedImage.extent){
            let uiblendedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgBlendedImage)



            image = Image(uiImage: uiblendedImage)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rendering from CIImage to CGImage is slow. The only way to make Core Image keep up with a slider is to portray the CIImage directly through a Metal view.

Comment: @matt Could you please share some links where can I start with Metal view or how it should be done in my case?

Comment: I can certainly show an example, but not for SwiftUI. For instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/51753747/341994

Comment: Thank you, this is really good startpoint :)

Comment: Mmmm, okay, but I think the real solution is to dig deeper and ask yourself whether you really need to be using Core Image at all. If the idea is just to draw with alpha, you don't.

Comment: I want to display blended images (so I assume CoreImage is needed here) and I want to control their alpha.

Comment: Well, as I say, if all you want to do is blend images, core image is completely unnecessary.

Comment: So how can I achieve blended images in Swift without using CIFilters? What should I search for?

Comment: I was thinking of simple UIImage methods like `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624095-draw`. It has a `blendMode` and `alpha` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`CIColorMatrix`](https://cifilter.io/CIColorMatrix/) filter to change the alpha of the images without loading the bitmap data again:

```
let colorMatrixFilter = CIFilter.colorMatrix()
colorMatrixFilter.inputImage = ciInputImage // no need to load that every time
colorMatrixFilter.inputAVector = CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0.5 + opacity)
let semiTransparentImage = colorMatrixFilter.outputImage

// perform blending
```